# Построение иерархии с помощью Python

Tags: python, pandas

Прошу помочь в решении следующей задачи.
В упрощенном виде: есть таблица вида

| таб номер подч | подчиненный | таб номер рук | руководитель |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 112233 | Ген. дер. | 123344456 | Вице-президент |
| 113213 | Гл. экономист | 112233 | Ген. дер. |
| 114213 | специалист | 112233 | Ген. дер. |
| 212233 | Слесарь | 12334 | Мастер |
| 353213 | Электрик | 12334 | Мастер |
| 12334 | Мастер | 45678 | Нач. цеха 1 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |

и т.д.

Всего записей в таблице порядка 117 тыс. строк.

Мне нужно вывести с помощью Python новую графу "верхнеуровневую подчиненность" в таблицу для дальнейшей группировки. Эта графа отражает верхнеуровневого руководителя

Что должно получиться:

| таб номер подч | подчиненный | таб номер рук | руководитель | верхнеур. подчиненность |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 112233 | Ген. дер. | 123344456 | Вице-президент | Вице-президент |
| 113213 | Гл. экономист | 112233 | Ген. дер. | Вице-президент |
| 114213 | специалист | 112233 | Ген. дер. | Вице-президент |
| 212233 | Слесарь | 12334 | Мастер | Нач. цеха 1 |
| 353213 | Электрик | 12334 | Мастер | Нач. цеха 1 |
| 12334 | Мастер | 45678 | Нач. цеха 1 | Нач. цеха 1 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |

и т.д.

Уровней "вхождения" в иерархию достаточно много. Здесь в примере указано 2 уровня вхождения для каждой из групп: Вице-президент и ген. директор, а также для второй группы Нач. цеха 1 и мастер. Уровни подчинения определяются следующим образом, например, если главный экономист и специалист подчинены генеральному директору, а тот, в свою очередь, подчиняется Вице-президенту, то и главный экономист и специалист также подчиняются Вице-президенту, поэтому напротив них в графе верхнеур. подчиненность должно стоять Вице-президент.

Использую такой код на Python:

```
df['верхнеур. подчиненность'] = df['таб номер рук'].map(df.set_index('таб номер подч')['подчиненный'])
```

Но получаю столбец, дублирующий поле руководитель.
Прошу подсказать, как доработать/изменить код и решить задачу.

Comment: Так у всех один высокий руководитель "Вице-президент". `df['верхнеур. подчиненность'] = "Вице-президент"` и всё. В чем подвох?

Comment: В примере - краткий срез всей таблицы. Должностей и уровней иерархии куда больше. Мне нужно кодом разнести эти уровни иерархии

Comment: В вопросе не описано правило как вычислять верхнеур. подчиненность. Желательно описать это правило и скорректировать вторую таблицу, чтобы там был не только ""Вице-президент"

Comment: Спасибо за совет. Исправил вводные. Надеюсь, в этом виде задание выглядит более корректно составленным.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Суть преобразования - объединить фрейм с самим собой, сопоставив поля  "руководитель" и "подчиненный" и взяв в целевое поле "руководителя руководителя".

Так, например "руководитель" "Ген. дер." сопоставляется с "подчиненный" "Ген. дер.", у которого забирается в целевое поле "руководитель" - "Вице-президент".

Поскольку высшие руководители не встречаются в поле "подчиненный", у них в целевом поле возникает NaN, который просто заполняется их руководителем, т.е. своей же должностью.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'таб номер подч': [112233, 113213, 114213, 212233, 353213, 12334], 'подчиненный': ['Ген. дер.', 'Гл. экономист', 'специалист', 'Слесарь', 'Электрик', 'Мастер'],
                   'таб номер рук': [123344456, 112233, 112233, 12334, 12334, 45678], 'руководитель': ['Вице-президент', 'Ген. дер.', 'Ген. дер.', 'Мастер', 'Мастер', 'Нач. цеха 1']})

df = (df.merge(df[['подчиненный', 'руководитель']], left_on='руководитель', right_on='подчиненный', how='left', suffixes=('', '_1'))
      .rename(columns={'руководитель_1': 'верхнеур. подчиненность'}).drop(columns='подчиненный_1'))
df['верхнеур. подчиненность'] = df['верхнеур. подчиненность'].fillna(df['руководитель'])
print(df)
```

```
   таб номер подч    подчиненный  таб номер рук    руководитель верхнеур. подчиненность
0          112233      Ген. дер.      123344456  Вице-президент          Вице-президент
1          113213  Гл. экономист         112233       Ген. дер.          Вице-президент
2          114213     специалист         112233       Ген. дер.          Вице-президент
3          212233        Слесарь          12334          Мастер             Нач. цеха 1
4          353213       Электрик          12334          Мастер             Нач. цеха 1
5           12334         Мастер          45678     Нач. цеха 1             Нач. цеха 1
```

Comment: Этот способ обработает подмастерье -> мастер -> начальник участка -> начальник цеха -> исполнительный директор -> глава совета директоров -> владелец компании?

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy не обработает, конечно. Я это спрашивал в первом комментарии к вопросу. Если так, то у всех получится главным руководителем одно лицо - самый главный босс. Как я понял из пояснений, нужно получить руководителя руководителя, т.е. подняться на 1 уровень выше.